# Putting Triggered email in Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, api, journeybuilder, sdk

I am using a triggered email to send email to a person who registers to my page. The triggered email works fine. However, I would like to send a next email to persons who open the previous triggered email. I don't know how to do that. I usually do that in a Journey, but not with triggered email. I can't find any feature in Journey Builder that relates to triggered email. If there is anyway to achieve my gold, please give me a suggestion.

Comment: What is the reason for not sending the first mail with journey builder in the first place?

Comment: Umm. I think you are right. I should implement a new API to inject contacts to Journey Builder and then send email to them instead of triggered email.

I am implementing it by following this link [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/postEvent.htm). Does SFMC FuelSDK support injecting contacts to Journey Builder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use the API entry event, and keep all emails in Journey Builder

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/how-to-fire-an-event.htm

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion will be to use the Automation Studio Audience entry event. The automation will contain a Query activity, looking into *Open* data view:
https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/using_the_query_activity/data_views/data_view_open/

You can then select the open events for that specific email, and use the Subscriber Key to inject the recipient into the journey.